# Jquery not working in the loaded content

Tags: jquery

It seems to have an easy solution but I couldn't figure it out yet, there are a thousand similar topics but none worked for me, So I'am asking this question in a very simple way,

I have a button, lets say button "A", I want to load a section of an external page when this button is being clicked,

after that section is loaded, there is another button("B") (inside the loaded content) that shows some hidden content using jQuery, the problem is this second button is not working.
i tried setting timeout, using .load('content.html #1, script'); &...

Here are the codes:
**Main page:**

```
<body>
<a href="#" id="load">Load</a>
<div id="holder"></div>

</body>
```

**contents page:**

```
<body>
<section id="1">
Content 111
<a href="#" id="show">Show...</a>
<div id="showhere"></div>
</section>
<section id="2">
Content 222
</section>

</body>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


   $("#load").click(function() {
        $('#holder')
           .html('<div> Loading</div>')
           .load('content.html #1');
    });

$("#show").click(function() {
        $('#showhere')
           .html('<p>here it is</p>')
    });

 });
```

## Edit:

Thanks all for your perfect answers,
for this case I think the shortest and simplest would be using .live
but the thing is This is just a sample to make things less complicated, in the real project I have a complicated jquery to be executed in the loaded content, it's not just about adding a .html element, So basically,I'm asking for a solution to make java script work on the loaded content, maybe some sort of reset or reload after content is loaded?

## Edit2:

Well, I haven't found a solution to this yet, so I decided to change my code, I'm adding .live to all functions, but there is another problem, I understand that for events I have to use something like

```
$("#show").live("click",function() {
```

instead of

```
 $("#show").click(function() {
```

but there are lots of more stuff which are not in a function, like:

```
var $itval = $("#holder li").length;
    $(".filters li input[value*='all']").parent().find('span').html($itval);

    $("#holder li, .played").show();

    $(".entry-made").hide();
```

is there any way to wrap a function which doesn't affect anything around the whole jquery stuff?

Answer (score 3):

Use the delegate version of [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to "extend" the event handler to the dynamically loaded content

```
$("#holder").on("click", "#show", function() {
        $('#showhere').html('<p>here it is</p>')
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is, you cant simply change all event to .on("whatever"... specially if you have lots of them, and there are more complicated jquery stuff like if and else which I don't really know how to add .on to them, so is there any way of making jquery work on each loaded section?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to bind event to dynamically added elements.

```
 $("#show").on("click","#show",function() {
       $('#showhere').html('<p>here it is</p>')
 });
```

Comment: $("#load").click(function() {
        $('#holder')
           .html('<div> Loading</div>')
           .load('content.html #1');
             $("#show").on("click",function() {
       $('#showhere').html('<p>here it is</p>')
 });

    });
It''s not working again!,
plz note that this is just a sample, I'm gonna use lots of jquery inside the loaded content, alot of fades and slides , where should I put them?

Comment: @Ajinkya: Please read the docs. You need the delegate version of `.on()`.

Comment: @Sonyflat: Use `.on()`, no need to change anything else.

Comment: @Ajinkya Where should I put .on()?

Comment: @Sonyflat: Check my updated answer. use `.on` where you want to bind evnt to *dynamically* added elementes ie. elements which are added after page loaded like elemetns added through ajax.

Comment: @Ajinkya Please read edit 2, how should I put .on or .live on those mentioned jquery?

Comment: @Sonyflat: Read about `.on()` it will help you to understand solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use live binding for this case. replace your current "#show onclick" to this version.

```
$("#show").live("click",function() {
    $('#showhere').html('<p>here it is</p>')
});
```

Comment: `live` is, of course, deprecated. Other than that, this is just a duplicate of previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that as of when you're trying to hook up the handler, the element *doesn't exist*, so nothing gets hooked up.

You can either

1. Use the `load` callback and hook things up directly once the elements actually exist, or
2. Use event delegation

#### 1. The `load` callback

Use the `load` callback if you want to hook up to a specific element in the loaded content:

```
$("#load").click(function() {
    $('#holder')
       .html('<div> Loading</div>')
       .load('content.html #1', function() { // <== This is the callback
            $("#show").click(function() {
                $('#showhere')
                   .html('<p>here it is</p>')
            });
       });
 });
```

#### 2. Event Delegation

Now, if you're going to be loading and unloading a lot of content you want to respond to events on, you might consider using *event delegation*. That's where you hook the event on the container, but tell jQuery to let you know it happened only if it actually started on a matching descendant of the container.

In your case, your `#holder` makes sense as a container:

```
$("#load").click(function() {
    $('#holder')
       .html('<div> Loading</div>')
       .load('content.html #1')
       .delegate("#show", "click", function() {
            $('#showhere')
               .html('<p>here it is</p>')
        });
 });
```

There I'm using [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) to set up the delegated event handler. You can also use the ridiculously-overloaded [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) (note the order of arguments is different):

```
       .on("click", "#show", function() {
```

...but I prefer the clarity of using `on` for direct handlers and `delegate` for delegated ones.

---

In the comments below, you've said

> ...the thing is I have lots of functions inside the loaded content, is there any way to make'em work without re coding?

I'm guessing that what you mean by "functions inside the loaded content" is that you have JavaScript in `content.html` that works on the elements in it, and you want to reuse that same script in this file.

The way you do that is to put that script in its own JavaScript file and have both `content.html` and your main page reference that file. Have the script not *execute* on load, but define functions (like `contentPageHookUpNiftyEvents`).

`content.html` can call that function right away, as soon as it loads (either directly if you put your `script` tag at the bottom of the file, as you should, or via `ready` if you have some reason for not doing that).

Your main page would call `contentPageHookUpNiftyEvents` from the `load` callback mentioned in #1 above.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your nice answer, this works perfectly , the thing is I have lots of functions inside the loaded content, is there any way to make'em work without re coding?

Comment: @Sonyflat: What do you mean by "functions" in the loaded content? I've taken a guess at what you mean and added a bit to the end of the answer, hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, Look, in this example we are just adding a .html element which is <p>here it is</p> in the loaded content after clicking a button, but I'm looking for a way to make a more complex jquery containing functions itself(like filtering, slider, show/hide, slide,...etc) work in the loaded area without having to code the whole thing againg.
Thanks

Comment: @Sonyflat: We may have had overlapping comments there, see the updated answer and let me know if that sorts things out.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort on solving my problem, maybe I'm not clear enough,
here is the thing,I'm trying to use .load to make my page load faster,currently I have around 5 js files and everything in my main page, what im trying to do is separating each section so when the user clicks on a menu item then only that section appears, So what I want is to make all js work inside that loaded content. I cant really take them all and put 'em in a script tag in my html, they are jquery codes which make loaded content of each section work.
hope its clear enough and  thanks again.

Comment: @Sonyflat: I'm not suggesting you put the JavaScript inside the HTML file. I'm suggesting you have an initialization function for each section, all in one JavaScript file (in production; separate ones for source control and such), which you load from a script tag at the bottom of your main page. Your `load` callback then triggers the appropriate initialization function for the section.

Comment: As you first mentioned the reason is that there is no element at first so nothing gets hooked up, so is there any way to tell it to look for element again once each menu item (#load button in this example) is clicked?

Comment: @Sonyflat: Note that `.load("content.html #1")` will load the **full** `content.html` page from the server, then throw away all of the content that doesn't match the selector. Also note that the selector `#1` is invalid, `id` selectors can't start with a digit. If you're trying to make your content modular, put each section in its own HTML fragment file.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder , I tried putting all javascript links at the bottom of the content.html page but still no luck, id selector is not an issue here as its differnt in the project.

Comment: @Sonyflat: Please re-read the answer and comments. Not the `content.html` page, the **main** page.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder as I mentioned earlier I have everything working on on main page, so of course I have those stuff in my main page, problem is when loading external content

Comment: @Sonyflat: Sorry, I can't explain it any more clearly than the end of the answer above, and I have a deadline I need to be working on. Good luck with it,